# Web Scraping using user agent to avoid from blocking by the website

Tags: r, web-scraping

I write a web scraping code with R on https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/.

I try to use `Sys.sleep()` to avoid detecting.

But every time I could only scrape 40 rows data and now totally blocked by the website.

I google how to solve this problem. Many people suggest using a user agent to solve it like

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25'
```

My questions which function(or where should I add argument) should I use to change the user agent?

My web scraping code is as follows:

```
path_1 = 'https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/?mfgr='
    page_path = paste(path_1, manufacturer[1], sep='') # change 1 to i
    path_2 = '&released='
    page_path = paste(page_path, path_2, sep='')
    page_path = paste(page_path, releasedate[1], sep='') # change 1 to j
    path_3 = '&sort=name'
    page_path = paste(page_path, path_3, sep='') # GPU list webage


    # ---------------GPU list---------------

    download.file(page_path, destfile = , quiet=TRUE)
    Sys.sleep(5)
    webpage = read_html("")
    node_name = paste('.vendor-', manufacturer[1], sep='') # change 1 to i

    gpu_data <- webpage %>% 
      html_nodes('.processors')  %>% html_nodes(node_name)  %>% 
      html_text()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The help page at `?download.file` tells you there is an optional `headers = ` argument, and User Agent should be the first one you supply.

Comment: Thanks Brian.

I try to add headers before but it still fails.

`download.file(headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25', page_path, destfile =, quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: You probably also need to prepend your string with `User-Agent: `, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: I tried again, it still fail.
`>     download.file(headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}, page_path, destfile = "C:/Users/ytsao/Documents/My Received Files/Melvin_20200330/gpu.html", quiet=TRUE)
Error in "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36" : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(headers = { : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Try `headers = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ..."` with the rest of the string. You can't pass in JSON object literals in R anyway the way you just tried to.

Comment: I try before I post the previous response because it shows the following message.
`>     download.file(headers = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
+                   page_path, destfile = "C:/Users/ytsao/Documents/My Received Files/Melvin_20200330/gpu.html", quiet=TRUE)`
`Error in download.file(headers = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36",  : 
  'headers' must have names and must not be NA`

Comment: The error message is telling you `headers must have names`. So `headers = c("User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 ..."` could be the right format. Or your IP could just be blocked altogether by the server from your initial scraping, so you'd need to contact the site to get unblocked.

Comment: Thanks Brian so much. I still fail. I think I blocked by the server completely. I will try other methods like a proxy. Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi Brian, I find out that the chrome extension, Hola, could provide VPN for me to browse the website normally. However, it still can not use the R code to scrape information. Is that possible to use the Hola through R Studio?